Chromes produces and keeps established a large number of connections
recently i have started to look/check the traffic on a Ubuntu 22.04 laptop and have discovered that chrome opens and keeps established a large amount of TCP connections
(see the screenshot).
Even when it starts with all extensions disabled and with no tabs opened it already has about 6 connections initiated.
At the same time with Firefox i can see that connections, which are not in use anymore, being dropped and new ones are being created only within the new request.
Can you please advice whether you are finding such behavior normal for this browser?
Thank you.
